# Why is my parser not working

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape the directory info from this website. `'http://www.virginiaequestrian.com/main.cfm?action=greenpages&sub=view&ID=10478'`

But i don't know how to select the different lines of text because their only tags are line break elements( 
). Is there a way that i can search by text rather than by tag?

```
r=requests.get('http://www.virginiaequestrian.com/main.cfm?action=greenpages&sub=view&ID=10478')
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
tbl=soup.findAll('table')[2]
print tbl.br
```

Comment: Well `print tbl.br` is specifically an instruction to print a `<br>` tag contained inside the table so I don't quite understand what you expected.

Comment: What did you expect the output of `print tbl.br` to be?

Comment: Guys i'm really new to this, so assign blame ignorance rather than stupidity please. I was hoping i could get the text value for each unit.  For instance the first part of the address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text you are looking for is in the 2nd TR inside the table. So,

```
print tbl.findAll('tr')[2]
```

There really isn't any good structure inside that text, however, so you're on your own about getting the contact name, etc.